# Match Any Word Except for A Single Word

Tags: regex

How do I write a regex to match any file that begins with "history_" except for "history_all"?

Comment: What **flavor** of regex? Perl? PHP? JavaScript? Java?

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: Actually I'm using it in a Makefile. I did not try, so I did not fail. I was looking for some guidance and I got it in the form of negative lookahead which led me to some wonderful documentation. Mucho gracias, Tikhon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to split it into two tests: `/history_\w+/` and then check that it isn't equal to `history_all`.

If you don't want to split it up, you can use something like `/history_(?!all\b)\w+/`.

Here the `(?!all\b)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which can be read as "not followed by `all[end of word]`".